# Yii2 - Code broke after composer update (Dektrium Yii2-User Profile)

Tags: php, timezone, yii2, composer-php, yii2-user

Today I did a composer update on my Yii2 project. During that time, Yii upgraded from 2.0.8 to 2.0.9. The following extensions I was using also upgraded...

```
  - Removing dektrium/yii2-user (0.9.6)
  - Installing dektrium/yii2-user (dev-master d9530a1)
    Cloning d9530a1b4213c2bd7fd8eb05d185dfe9dffde558

  - Updating dektrium/yii2-rbac dev-master (4254915 => 0943e
    Checking out 0943e66c450132b306584a37caefc2aa04258372
```

Once the updates happened, I was unable to save (update) my User's Profile records. I rechecked the deployment server and it works there.

I used the "$model->getErrors()" function to see what error I get, and it said...

> Time zone is not valid

I am not sure what the Time zone has to do with the User record, or the associate Profile record in Yii2. I have reached out to the extension developer, but any suggestions while I wait for his reply would be appreciated.

I tried setting it in the formatter section of web.php config file, as below...

```
'defaultTimeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
```

My php.ini file has...

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

I even tried deleting and adding a new user, but no joy.

I am totally stumped, and not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a validation of `Profile->timezone` attribute. As you can see [here](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/8d97431db8596d19738d5ca2928b5e50ed997016/models/Profile.php).

In your table, you must have the `timezone` column and it's value must be a [valid timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Yep, was going to post a solution, but you beat me to it. I had to apply a migration that was required for this latest version.